# Python, mutable object as default argument, is there any way to solve?

Tags: python, class, object, mutable

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n=[0]):
        self.data = n

a = A()
print a.data[0] #print 0
a.data[0] +=1

b = A()
print a.data[0] #print 1, desired output is 0
```

In the case above, is there any way to provide a default argument with the mutable object (such as list or class) in __init__() **class A**, but **b** is not affected by the operation **a**?

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+mutable+default+arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n=None):
        if n is None:
            n = [0]
        self.data = n
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, n=None):
       if n is None:
         n = [0]
       self.data = n
```

Which avoids the biggest problem you're facing here, that is, that's the same list for every single object of your type "A."

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n=[0]):
        print id(n)
        self.data = n[:]
        print id(self.data)
        del n


a = A()
print a.data[0] #prints 0
a.data[0] +=1
print a.data[0] #prints 1

print

b = A()
print b.data[0] #prints desired output  0
```

The principle is that it creates another list. If a long list is passed as argument, there will be two long list in memory. So the inconvenience is that it creates another list.... That's why I delete **n**.

Don't think it's better, but it may give you comprehension of what happens